# Retrying to show location | Google Maps Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

I use google maps in my Flutter app to show the current location of the user. In most cases this works without any problems. However, if the user has permanently denied the access location permission and this permission is granted by the user after building the map widget, the location of the user is not displayed. It seems to me that the only reason for this is that the permission was not granted at the time of build. Now I am wondering if it is possible to retry displaying the location after the permission is granted. My first thought was to not to show a Google Map at all when the permission is denied and to only display it when it is granted. But at least when using an if / else statement, this does not work for the same reason. Thank you for any advice.

EDIT: For now I have settled with drawing the circles on the map manually in this edge case.